# Change default naming conventions by windows explorer using AHK

Tags: rename, autohotkey, explorer

currently, what happens in windows explorer when highlighting and batch renaming files/folders is as such:

```
test(1).jpg
test(2).jpg
test(3).jpg
```

how do i code a script such that highlighting the files/folders and hitting the same hotkey (f2) allows me to change the naming convention?

Variable {space} ###.jpg

where Variable is the name for user input and ### is the running sequence starting from 001?

in addition, i need the script to IGNORE warnings when there's already another file with the previous same name. one possible way to overcome this is to temporarily rename the offending file to a temp name first, so that the renamer can continue with its correct sequence.

Yes, i do know there are many capable applications that can already do the simple job above - but i prefer NOT to have a GUI (since it's v simple).

appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: So is this solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

consider this example :

```
#Include Explorer.ahk ;get it from : https://github.com/denolfe/AutoHotkey/blob/master/lib/Explorer.ahk

F2::
InputBox, Variable, Rename files, Enter your filename prefix.,, 250, 150,,,,,DefaultPrefix
path := Explorer_GetPath()
sel := Explorer_GetSelected()

MsgBox % sel
if ( StrLen(sel) && FileExist(path) )
{
    Loop, Parse, sel, `n
    {
        SetWorkingDir, %path%
        MsgBox  %A_loopfield%
        FileMove,  %A_loopfield%, %Variable%_%A_index%.*, 1 ; the '1' means Overwrite
    }
}
return
```

Comment: hi there. i downloaded explorer.ahk together with your script, but the only thing that (apparently) worked was the msgbox only. win explorer did not respond to the hotkey thereafter.

Comment: are you using ahk v1.1? what is your OS version?

Comment: I'm using AHK Version v1.1.15.04, OS Win 8.1 x64.

The msgbox just popped up and there was no way for user input.

Comment: hmmm have you selected a file in explorer, then hit F2?

Comment: yes of course - gave me a bunch of popups and subsequently renamed it to "BlahBlah" instead of user input.

Comment: Ahh yes, i see what you are looking for. I have updated the code. This example should suffice your needs. :)